# Why is my Windows 10 charmap UI layout 'messed up'?

Tags: windows-10, gui, win32

I'm not really sure how to describe it, so here's a picture. I added the red arrows to highlight some of the things that look wrong.

Windows 10 Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3930)

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: Try running DISM followed by SFC.  After that update Windows  10 including optional updates

Comment: have you modified your systems DPI settings? I believe the Charmap is one of the older windows system utilities, and older windows apps don't like a non-default DPI. if you have Display Scaling enaled, try setting it to 100% temporarilly to test whether everything displays correctly then.